# Laravel redirection into an Iframe on Safari

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, iframe, safari

I have an Iframe from `https://site-a.com/` embeb into `https://site-b.com/`.
For example, the first page of the Iframe is : `https://site-a.com/module`.

There is a form into the Iframe. When the form has errors, I redirect back with input and errors.
`redirect()->back()->withErrors(['genericError' => $e->getMessage()])->withInput();`

On Safari, this not working, Safari always redirect the user to origin domain : `https://site-a.com/` instead of `https://site-a.com/module/{previous_url}`. When I print `URL::previous()` on Safari, it returns `https://site-a.com/`. So, the `URL::previous()` seems to be incorrect on Safari when we are in an Iframe.

On each other navigators, it's working correctly.

`<iframe src="my_url" sandbox="allow-top-navigation allow-storage-access-by-user-activation allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups"></iframe>`